# how to get DataGridViewColumns out of IOrderedEnumerable with DataGridviewCell's?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a datagridview where I select a selection of cells, then order them ready for processing.

```
var q = Dat.SelectedCells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
       .OrderBy(x => x.RowIndex);//order selectedCells by row-index

var p = q.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(x => x.ColumnIndex);
```

var p is now a list of IOrderedEnumerable filled with datagridviewCells.

My question is: How can i get the first and last DataGridViewColumn out of p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the index of the first and last columns from the initial cells collection:

```
var firstColumnIndex = q.Min(c => c.ColumnIndex);
var lastColumnIndex = q.Max(c => c.ColumnIndex);
```

Comment: sounds easy...(will try after dinner)